# conflicto entre librería de OpenLayers y Concurrent.Thread.js

Tags: javascript, hilos, openlayers

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto con open layers para renderizar mapas, muestro diferentes puntos en el mapa, pero necesito todos esos puntos, en distintos tiempos para realizar algo así como un replay, pero al momento de cargar la data el sitio se bloquea hasta que tenga toda la data, por lo que he planteado como solución traerla por partes, de modo que si son 10000 series, pueda traer 100 e iniciar el replay, mientras sigue cargando los siguientes 100 y así traer toda la data a medida que el usuario va visualizando los que ya han cargado (similar a la carga de videos), pero para esto necesito que el proceso de carga se ejecute en segundo plano por lo que optado por trabajar con la librería [Concurrent.Thread.js](https://geekytheory.com/concurrencia-en-javascript); independientemente, funciona bien y hace exactamente lo que necesito, pero al incluirlo a mi proyecto, al parecer entra en conflicto con la librería de open layers, he creado un proyecto simple en el que solo trabajo con estas dos librerías y obtengo el mismo problema, el código es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Concurrent.Thread.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function proceso () {
            while (true) {
                console.log("HOLA MUNDO");
            }
        }
        Concurrent.Thread.create(proceso);
    </script>
    <div id="map" class="map">
    </div>

        <script>
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

En este caso el mapa no se muestra y obtengo el mismo error que me da en el proyecto principal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La librería de Concurrent.Thread.js que estoy usando la pueden encontrar [aquí](https://github.com/bringmehome/Concurrent.Thread.js)

Cómo puedo evitar el conflicto, de ser ese el problema,o que otra librería puedo usar que me permita ejecutar funciones javascript tal como Concurrent.Thread.js?